# How-To Build a Printer Setup

Tags: printer, network-printer, ink

My Current Printer Photosmart C3100, with a inbult scanner.

I plan on upgrading it.

I want to build a Printer Setup.

Something I can attach to the printer, via thin pipes or tubes to the Ink reservoir and use it long term.

Can someone guide me which is cheaper? Laser or Inkjet.

The Setup has to be cheap and if it has a built in wifi and a scanner its a bonus.

Spending one time on the printer can be streched but in the long run, the ink should run me cheaper. if need be please suggest two printers, a laser for b&w and inkjet for color!!

Comment: Inkjets are *never* cheaper in the long run.

Comment: I think this is a shopping recommendation, which is off topic.

Comment: A search term you might use for research is CISS (continuous ink supply system). CISS ink in bulk is cheaper than laser toner in carts, but not cheaper than laser toner in bulk. It depends, and there are many many factors to consider for any of it. Ex: Laser toners can live longer in time exposed, long term. CISS cart and toner refills are always messy and not without problems, although with a great need, and much research on quality and the lack of etc it can be worth it if you have Mass needs. For normal uses dont even bother :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'm not going to suggest models. I'm going to point out *rough* charecteristics to look for.

I've seen office printers that use *bottles* of toner to print - dirt cheap, easy to get toner, but fairly large startup costs.

Alternately, you could find a printer that you can refill with aftermarket inks (i've had good luck refilling canons, but i even managed to work out that you can refill dell printers or others) - i use a syringe and ink, but you could also go for a [CIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_ink_system) type refill system.

Both approaches may work well if you can get a functional, older printer.